# Converting entries from a multiple object JSON file into separate list lines

Tags: python, arrays, json, list

I have a JSON file which was used to provide responses for a chatbot. As a result, this intent file has multiple objects, each containing `"tag"`, `"patterns"`, and `"response"` entries.

For example (silly entries, the original file isn't in English and this serves to show the functionality):

```
{
  "intents":
  [
    {
      "tag": "indoor",
      "patterns": ["indoors", "windows", "inside", "shut", "door"],
      "response": ["If you are inside, don't forget to take off your shoes!"],
    },
    {
      "tag": "outdoor",
      "patterns": ["outdoors", "nature", "wind", "sun"],
      "response": ["If you are outside, enjoy the sun!"],
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to convert these so that every line of the object/list contains ONE object's patterns, so `[0, 0]` would contain the first pattern entry of the first tag (= `"indoors"`, `[0, 1]` the second pattern entry of the first tag (= `"windows"`); and `[1, 0]` would be the first pattern entry of the second tag category (= `"outdoors"`).

How do I do that? I can't quite figure out how to "know" when one intent ends and another starts. Parsing ALL the pattern entries into a list is not issue (I found multiple how-tos), but this makes it impossible to discern between the different entries via different lines. I want to KNOW which tag count the patterns belong to. (So I can assess the match count of the input and the respective categories in a separate list. I am aware that there are better ways to do this, but want to tackle it this way.)

Comment: What do `[0, 0]`, `[0, 1]`, and `[1, 0]` mean / signify? Please [edit] your question and show what the resulting list lines should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `json` module.

```
import json

your_dic = {}
data = json.loads('your text as file', strict=False)
your_dic[0] = data['data']['tag']
```

Will need to play around to get desired functionality.